# Unable to populate a KDE Quicklaunch widget via the Plasma Scripting Interface?

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu, kde, plasma

I'm customising the KDE desktop environment for our corporate desktop, and I've found what I hope is not a bug -

In short, all I want to do is add a quicklaunch widget to the panel, then populate it with some application shortcuts via the plasma scripting interface.

I have code that I believe should work:

```
//new panel for testing purposes
var panel = new Panel;
var quicklaunch = panel.addWidget("org.kde.plasma.quicklaunch");  
var qlurls = ["file:///usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop",
          "file:///usr/share/applications/org.kde.dolphin.desktop"
         ];
quicklaunch.currentConfigGroup = ["General"];
quicklaunch.writeConfig("launcherUrls", qlurls);
//confirm it's written correctly
print(quicklaunch.readConfig("launcherUrls"));
//flailing for ideas now?!?
quicklaunch.reloadConfig()
```

You can test it by starting the scripting console in a KDE session, and copying and pasting:

```
qdbus org.kde.plasmashell /PlasmaShell showInteractiveConsole
```

This correctly adds a new panel, a quicklaunch widget, and applies all the same settings that were applied when I interrogated a manually created quicklaunch, but - it doesn't display any of the application shortcuts, just a rocket icon.

What am I doing wrong?

[UPDATE] Confirming it's a bug - I have tested on the KDE Neon distribution, which includes newer plasma packages, and this code works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been playing around with your code:
If you use:

```
var qlurls = ["file:///usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop",
          "file:///usr/share/applications/org.kde.dolphin.desktop"
         ];
```

you should get your panel with the application shortcuts.

Comment: Thanks for checking it out - that is (was, edited) indeed missing, but still doesn't apply on the 16.04 plasma packages. It does work as intended on KDE neon though, so it's def a bug.

Comment: For me it worked. But I am indeed on KDE Neon.